# Haman's daughter's name

Tags: names, tractate-megillah, haman

Masechet Megilah says that Haman's daughter threw the garbage on him. Does the gemoro mention her name anywhere?

I looked in Gemora Megilla 16a where the story is but it does not mention a name. Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 5):

The *midrashim* I found don't mention her name, but it seems that her name is mentioned in some old Aramaic translations of Esther.

I couldn't find one of these versions, but her name is mentioned as either "שבחטנות" ([under "מדרשים"](http://www.aspaklaria.info/005_HE/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F.htm)) or "שכחטנת" ([page 3, comment 20](http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/58_28_74.pdf)) or "שלחטוות" ([page 4, comment 147](http://shtaygen.net/leaflet/ichud/73/3-2.pdf)).

Comment: You can find it in the Targum Sheni, printed in the back of the Mossad Harav Kook Megillat Esther.